# AVPlayer won't play sound iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, ios8

I was busy creating a simple app which plays songs from soundcloud. but for some weird reason my app wont play any sounds.
I checked by using breakpoints if the piece of code are executed and they are. but when the code is executed there no sound. I tried it on Sim and Device.

I import these frameworks in my view

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@import AVFoundation;
@import AVKit;
```

I added both so i could try solutions for each framework.

I've tried:

```
NSString *urlstr=@"http://www.3rdeyelab.com/mp3/mp3/tailtoddle_lo.mp3";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
AVPlayer *player;
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

And with a local file:
The mp3 file has the correct target selected.

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                           URLForResource:@"LongNight"
                                                           withExtension:@"mp3"]];
    [playerViewController.player play];
```

Both wont play any sound..
Ultimately i would like to play the url which is in the JSON repsonse from soundcloud but i wanted to start of small.

Thanks in advance, i hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlay]`

before trying to play any sound.